# convert Panda Line graph to Bar graph with month name

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I am trying to convert Line garph to Bar graph using python panda.

Here is my code which gives perfect line graph as per my requirement.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Demo.db')

collection = ['ABC','PQR']
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Table where ...", conn)
df['DateTime'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x))


df.groupby('Type').plot(x='DateTime', y='Value',linewidth=2)
plt.legend(collection)
plt.show()
```

Here is my DataFrame df
http://postimg.org/image/75uy0dntf/

Here is my Line graph output from above code.
http://postimg.org/image/vc5lbi9xv/

I want to draw bar graph instead of line graph.I want month name on x axis and value on y axis. I want colorful bar graph.

Attempt made

```
df.plot(x='DateTime', y='Value',linewidth=2, kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

It gives improper bar graph with date and time(instead of month and year) on x axis. Thank you for help.

Comment: with your attempt, is the bar graph what you want except for wrong labels?

Comment: Yes labels are not proper and it should display separate type (as bar) for each month-year. Check this http://postimg.org/image/5m9s2y2mr/

Comment: it does not solve your problem but don't you want to group by 'Type' before making the bar plot? `df.groupby('Type').plot(x='DateTime', y='Value',linewidth=2, kind='bar')`

Comment: I also tried with groupby 'Type'. It doesn't work. It gives separate bar for each day.

Comment: do you have to use pandas plotting methods? otherwise you can always do it manually directly in matplotlib

Comment: I am not strict with panda, I want result in any condition, Method doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you have solution ?

Comment: I just posted an answer. I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that might do what you want.

In this code, I first sort your database by time. This step is important, because I use the indices of the sorted database as abscissa of your plots, instead of the timestamp. Then, I group your data frame by type and I plot manually each group at the right position (using the sorted index). Finally, I re-define the ticks and the tick labels to display the date in a given format (in this case, I chose MM/YYYY but that can be changed).

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

types = ['ABC','BCD','PQR']*3
vals = [126,1587,141,10546,1733,173,107,780,88]
ts = [1414814371, 1414814371, 1406865621, 1422766793, 1422766793, 1425574861, 1396324799, 1396324799, 1401595199]

aset = zip(types, vals, ts)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=aset, columns=['Type', 'Value', 'Timestamp'])
df = df.sort(['Timestamp', 'Type'])
df['Date'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%m/%Y'))

groups = df.groupby('Type')
ngroups = len(groups)
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, position=[0.15, 0.15, 0.8, 0.8])
offset = 0.1
width = 1-2*offset
#
for j, group in enumerate(groups):
    x = group[1].index+offset
    y = group[1].Value
    ax.bar(x, y, width=width, color=colors[j], label=group[0])

xmin, xmax = min(df.index), max(df.index)+1
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', top='off', bottom='off')
plt.xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax)+0.5, list(df['Date']), rotation=90)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

I hope this works for you. This is the output that I get, given my subset of your database.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting answer. Can you tell me how can i get month name/ year instead of month/year. i.e April / 2015

Comment: In your definition of `df['Date']`, you can customize `strftime` to what you need. Check this link for all possibilities: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior. In this case, you can use `'%b %Y'` => `Apr 2014` or `'%B %Y'` => `April 2014`. If the label becomes too long, you will only see the end of it =>  you can adjust the `position` of the axes to solve that, or rotate the labels by 45 degrees instead of 90.